# I need help to solve my melting switch problem

Tags: automotive, toggle-switch

I have used a 20A 12VDC switch which by-passes my air-conditioning climate switch in the car which is not functioning, and yes... The 20A melted. My car battery is 12V. I have a glass fuse installed before the switch which is 20A.

I can't get a spare AC climate control switch, as in my country there are none. This is my second purchase of a 20A switch.

I seriously need help.

Comment: Are you sure your AC pump is good? If it's damaged, it could draw much more current than when it's working properly.

Comment: If the 20 A fuse is in *series* with the switch and didn't blow, then the supposed "20 A" switch is faulty and couldn't handle the current. To be sure, put an ammeter that can handle at least 30 A in series and check the current.

Comment: Apparently you have designed a switch that has failed twice.  Next time ensure it is done right with a suitable arc suppression snubber. RC or diode + MOV. 20Adc is only rated for resistive loads

Comment: this sounds like an `X-Y problem` ..... some failure has damaged the climate control switch and you are asking help with what you consider to be the solution to the problem, instead of asking for help with the real problem

Comment: Electronic or physical switch?

Comment: A switch could be rated for AC or DC voltage and current, inductive loads/ heavy duty or not, and may be rated to switch only so often, so chances are a heavier duty switch/relay is in order.  Because of the current spikes Sunnyskyguy mentions, the fuse is probably some form of slower-blowing fuse averaging 20A and the switch is actually being asked to do more than it is rated for.

Comment: @jsotola, you're right. My climate control switch became faulty, and that put me in this position. Would post a picture of the faulty climate control switch asap, maybe anyone with the same model could identify with similar problems.

Comment: @RookieEl'Engineer, you are misunderstanding my comment ....... I am saying that you may have a failure with another component that caused the climate control switch to fail and it is causing the bypass switches to also fail

Comment: @KH, it's a physical switch

Comment: Also, switches may be rated for AC 20A, which may not work at 20A DC. Usually when the switches actually transition, it causes a brief higher resistance condition which may lead to a cascading thermal runaway.

Comment: What brand switch?  I would not trust the Chinese-made switches from Amazon for example.  How about a closeup picture of the switch?

Comment: Also, I would be reluctant to run a switch at much more than 50% of rating.

Comment: @jsotola.. Thanks for the correction. Note taken with gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

The load that is being switched in your AC is the clutch that engages the compressor, which is itself belt-driven by the engine, so isn't part of the electrical load. The clutch is held against the driving face of the pulley by a large electromagnet, and like all such devices, holds a significant amount of energy in the magnetic field, so there's is a diode connected in parallel, that allows the current to decay in a controlled fashion and not generate large arcs across the switch. 
  Below is a common arrangement for the AC clutch wiring, I assume your switch is taking the place of the relay. If the diode has failed or become disconnected, there's a good chance that significant damage is being done to the contacts every time you turn it off, even though the current is not high enough to cause overheating or fuse failure in a steady state - typically it will be a few amps. The arcing at the contacts will increase the contact resistance over time causing the switch to eventually melt.
  The diode is typically on the back of the compressor, or built into the wiring harness nearby, but could also be in the fusebox as a plug-in device.

[image]